# How do I get the double Square root of a number

Tags: javascript

I need to get a double square root of a number but my codes won't work:

```
function doubleSquareRootOf(num) {
  return num * num * num;
}

var output = doubleSquareRootOf(121);
console.log(output); // --> it must return 22 but its displaying 1771561
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is a “double square root”? Two times the square root? Do you know how to get the square root of a number?

Comment: `return num * num * num;` that's num cubed!! `Math.sqrt` or `Math.pow` may be more what you need ... double square root ... `return 2 * Math.sqrt(num);` or `return 2 * Math.pow(num, 0.5)` - do you even know what a square root is?

Comment: I suspect he means cube root.

Comment: no, because square root of 121 = 11, and 11 x 2 = 22 - look at the expected result

Comment: He needs sqrt(num)*2 (that 2 is the 'double')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try sqrt * 2 instead of cubing the num

```
return Math.sqrt(num)*2;
```

Answer (score -1):

math.sqrt(math.sqrt(number)) -> this is a double square root of a number

Comment: That doesn't match OP's expectations.